# how to i make a live ubuntu on my usb with persistence that can boot both from pc and mac?

Tags: live-usb

I've got a 64 Gb usb stick that i want a live ubuntu install on with persistence so i can store my files on it but... her comes the catch

i need the install to work both with pc(64bit) and mac(64bit) with intel processors
i can install it so i can boot it from my mac
and i can install it so i can install it from my pc
but i can't install it so it will boot successful up on both.

is this possible or am i aiming to high here?
if its possible can anyone point me towards how to do it?

on advance THANKS

Comment: With a 64 GB stick I highly suggest you do a standard installation. Persistence is "ok" if you wish to make a small number of changes, but does not replace a standard install. Persistence becomes buggy if you install or update a lot of packages and, due to the need to track changes, eventually will take up more space then a standard install. Alternately you can partition the flash drive and simply use a separate partition for data.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/),

```
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

The process is easy from there.